# MySQL Syntax for linking two rows from different tables, where they both have a common field

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I've got a MySQL Database containing several tables and I've got to create a pretty complicated query to get the data I need from these tables, and I am having issues crating said query.

The tables are designed as so (the column names have been renamed, these arn't the actual columns),

Table1
    id, name, rating, country

Table2
    itemid, textbool1, textbool2

The query needs to:-

- Check that the table2.textbool1 and table2.textbool2 fields match the inputted string (provided externally, through string concatenation)
- (Bearing in mind that id = itemid)
- Check that name contains the inputted string
- Check that rating is above a certain value
- Check that country matches the inputted string
- Return the contents of a maximum of 20 table2 rows, sorted by table1.rating (Descending)

So far, I have this:-

```
SELECT table2.* from table2 INNER JOIN table1 
WHERE table2.textbool1 = 'true' && table2.textbool2 = 'false' 
&& table1.name LIKE 'test' && table1.rating >= '10' && table1.country = 'gb' 
ORDER BY table1.rating DESC LIMIT 20
```

But this isn't working. Can anybody explain why?

Any help would be appriciated.

**Edit**

This query works: `SELECT table2.* FROM table2 INNER JOIN table 2 ON(table2.item_id = table1.id) WHERE table1.country= 'de' && premiumservers.Rating >= 9 ORDER BY table1.Rating DESC LIMIT 20`

But this does not: `SELECT table2.* FROM table2 INNER JOIN tabel1 ON(table2.item_id = table1.id) WHERE table1.Name LIKE 'test' && table1.country = 'de' ORDER BY table1.Rating DESC LIMIT 20`

Comment: **table1.rating >= '10'** is it string or int?

Comment: Use proper JOIN syntax `table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.itemid=table1.id...`

Comment: table1.rating is a mediumint

Comment: isn't not working means... whether query showing error or not getting expected result?

Comment: Not getting expected result, i'm not getting any errors from MySQL.

Comment: Edit your question with some sample data,desired results.

Comment: And don't use `&&`. The operator is `AND`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `ON` statement in `INNER JOIN`

Try this..

```
SELECT table2.* from 
table2 INNER JOIN table1
ON( table2.itemid = table1.id )
WHERE table2.textbool1 = 'true' && table2.textbool2 = 'false' 
&& table1.name LIKE '%test%' && table1.rating >= '10' && table1.country = 'gb' 
ORDER BY table1.rating DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Okay, this is the query now. `SELECT table2.* FROM table2 INNER JOIN tabel1 ON(table2.item_id = table1.id) WHERE table1.Name LIKE 'test' && table1.country = 'de' ORDER BY table1.Rating DESC LIMIT 20` But it's still not working.

Comment: Okay, this query works. `SELECT table2.* FROM table2 INNER JOIN table 2 ON(table2.item_id = table1.id) WHERE table1.country= 'de'  ORDER BY table1.Rating DESC LIMIT 20`

Comment: But when it includes the "LIKE" parts, it doesn't work.

Comment: Updated the answer.. Basically when you want to search within strings, you need to use `%` character..